# GML: check ds_queue or ds_stack for equality (identical contents)

Tags: game-maker

Is there a nondestructive way to check whether two queues or stacks contain identical values? For example:

```
foo=ds_queue_create();
ds_queue_enqueue(foo, 1);
ds_queue_enqueue(foo, 2);

bar=ds_queue_create();
ds_queue_enqueue(bar, 3);
ds_queue_enqueue(bar, 1);
ds_queue_enqueue(bar, 2);
ds_queue_dequeue(bar);

return(equality_test(foo, bar));
```

should return `true`

Options I know of:

- `foo == bar` returns `false`, presumably because it's checking whether they point to the same queue as opposed to having the same values.
- `ds_queue_write(foo) == ds_queue_write(bar)` seems to be sensitive to the queues' histories. If I just enqueue `[1,2]` on each queue, it gives `true`. But because I added and then dequeued an irrelevant value on `bar`, the serialized strings differ even though the current values are identical.
- Iterating through the items one at a time and checking equality works for arrays, but doing this using `ds_queue_dequeue` destroys the queues. Is there a nondestructive way to read elements of a queue, other than the head and tail?
- Per liggiorgio's comment below, I could duplicate the queues with `ds_queue_copy` and destructively iterate over the duplicates -- is this the best way?

As far as I know the same issues apply to stacks.

Comment: Your third approach is fine, you could create a copy of each data structure you need and then check their respective values: the original data is fine since you're working on clones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your third approach is just fine, apart from being 'destructive' towards original data. But you can easily copy and clone the data to separate structures, and use these instead to check equality among values.

You may want to use simple `ds_list`s and take advantage of the function [`ds_list_find_value()`](https://docs.yoyogames.com/source/dadiospice/002_reference/data%20structures/ds%20lists/ds_list_find_value.html) to search for L1's values in L2's.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I had some unrelated reasons for preferring a queue, but using a list does sound like it might be less of a faff.

Comment: Then you can keep a copy of a `ds_queue` to dequeue the next value from, and copy & convert the other data in a `ds_list` to exploit its function `ds_list_find_value` and avoid implementing a search feature yourself.